# Noob flails about hopelessly

Tags: applescript, word-count

So, I found [this code](http://collabedit.com/n4xju) from [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=136205) by Nigel Garvey, and I want to add an ignore list similar to `set wordsToIgnore to {"and", "the", "a", "for", "in", "is"}`. The problem is I'm generally incompetent when it comes to these things. Can the powers that be take pity, and tell me how to add a ignore list? I've tried various types of frequency counts, but this one gives a correctly styled output in text edit, and is able to cut down the outputted words to a given number, but lacks the ability to ignore certain words. best regards.

Edit: I did post earlier with similar tags, but because I was working with a different script I thought it best to begin a new post. If I did wrong my apologies.

Comment: Why do you want to add another set? Why not just extend the current one?

Comment: i'm not seeing where there is a current ignore list, but this is probably because I don't know what I'm looking at. I've looked at this for hours, but again these are things of which I know not. suggestions?

Comment: To quote How to Ask Questions The Smart Way: [Groveling is not a substitute for doing your homework](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idp54052224).

Comment: @user3334951: You've listed the variable in that filters words... Just change that variable.

Comment: not deliberately groveling, i have tried and tried. i've just been hammered with a series of tests, and my brain is probably fried. yes, i thought someone who does this everyday could cease my floundering.

Comment: @anon so i insert the wordsToIgnore set initially, but I don't know where to insert the `if currentWord is not in wordsToIgnore then`

Comment: some examples i've seen have an `else` after the then, and i'm not sure what thats about either

Comment: The example given already has that stuff in there for you, does it not? Therefore you shouldn't need to insert `if currentWord is not in wordsToIgnore then`.

Comment: i don't believe it does. [here](http://collabedit.com/n4xju) it is again. point to a line and i'll shut my mouth

Comment: when i add the `set ignoreList` inside `main`, and then call the `if currentWord is not` i get _The run handler is specified more than once, or there were top-level commands in addition to the run handler._ if i put `set ignoreList` inside main and then call the `if currentWord is not` i get _Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier._ at line 61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this but after a quick look here's what I think. Change this section in the "on main(pdfFile)" handler to the following...

```
-- Go through the sorted list, counting the instances of each word. Store each word and its score in a list in the 'scores' list in the script object above.
set wordsToIgnore to {"and", "the", "a", "for", "in", "is"}
set currentWord to item 1 of o's wrds
set c to 1
repeat with i from 2 to (count o's wrds)
    set thisWord to item i of o's wrds
    if thisWord is not in wordsToIgnore then
        if (thisWord is currentWord) then
            set c to c + 1
        else
            set end of o's scores to {currentWord, c}
            set currentWord to thisWord
            set c to 1
        end if
    end if
end repeat
set end of o's scores to {currentWord, c}
```

Comment: i just noticed you are one of the original posters in the macscripter thread above. how cool. thanks again.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the "call method" code from my script in that thread no longer works. As such you need to use a 3rd party app (Skim) to extract the text from the pdf. But it works. Glad to help. Good luck.